# Reopen question request (serialization problem in .NET)

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed

I asked for an answer to a specific serialization problem in .NET. I gave the format my source data was in, and a sample of how I would like the output. How does that not fit into a Q&A format?

[How to serialize an object collection / dictionary into <key>value</key>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421970/how-to-serialize-object-collection-dictionary-into-keyvalue-key)

Comment: Looks legit to me, voted to reopen. I just hope it won't get into open/close war as it usually not ending well to either side.

Comment: I don't see the problem either, at the very least as of [rev 2](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12421970/revisions). Voting to re-open as well.

Comment: @jacko, question is opened now :)

Comment: FYI, "looking for code samples" isn't a good SO question. "We've currently got this code [...] that serializes to [...] but can't figure out how to transform it into [...]" (Note that I have no knowledge of the topic at hand so wouldn't have voted either way.)

Comment: thank you all - do i now close this question?

Comment: Let the community decide, maybe we can leave it open for now if moderator or developer want to post official answer (e.g. how to properly ask such things)

Answer (score 2):

From my personal experience, flagging a question for moderator's attention with a note explaining your point is the fastest way of getting the question re-opened. Of course it is possible to take your case straight to the community by posting on meta, but the moderators are usually very efficient, so flagging may save you some effort.

Obviously, this assumes that the root cause that lead to closing the question has been eliminated; otherwise, moderators would reject your request.

Comment: Flagging the question without fixing it first won't lead to a reopening and actually the chances will be very low (the reason for closing it still exists after all).

Comment: @Alenanno Thanks for the clarifications!

Comment: I didn't even realise that's what flagging was for. The SO faq mentions voting for reopening and that's it - not particularly clear. Hence why I came here.

Comment: @jacko In general, flagging is to attract moderator's attention. Usually it is something negative (spam, insults, "me too"s, and so on), but asking to re-open a question is among valid reasons to flag as well.